# openssl pkcs12 export error

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

when using the following :openssl pkcs12 -export -in < CAfilename1.cer > -out < CAfilename.cer2.p12> -name < “alias name”> /nhin/nss-3.12.4/bin/pk12util -i < CAfilename.cer2.p12> -n < alias name> -d $AS_HOME/domains/nssdomain/config"

the processs does not complete.  instead it gives me suggested options and states that there is an error in pkcs12.... i'm of course using the correct cert and p12 file names etc.... without the < and > and still get the error... please help....

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these instructions in the below link:

http://help.globalscape.com/help/secureserver3/Generating_a_PKCS_12_private_key_public_certificate.htm